# .htaccess not working on live system

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

i'm using the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*),(.*).html$   news.php?id=$2 [L]
```

when using eg. the following url:

```
http://www.foo.com/news/bar,303.html
```

it works on my local xampp but not on the live server .. var_dump($_GET) returns an empty array so the filter doesn't define the id parameter.
any ideas what is wrong?

EDIT: i have mod_rewrite installed and it works for most links just not this one ..

Comment: make sure you have mod rewrite installed and running on your live server

Comment: if `var_dump($_GET)` is completely empty, then something is very wrong. even if the script does get executed with `...?id=` and no value, you'd STILL have `$_GET['id'] = null` in the array.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule appears to be fine. On your live server `MultiViews` option might be enabled. To turn it off use:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

at top of your .htaccess.

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/news` is the URL then Apache will serve `/news.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite installed, it may not be active globally and requires to be activated

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /news/
 RewriteRule ^news/(.*),(.*).html$   news.php?id=$2 [L]
```

eg; turn rewrite on, and specify which directly to apply the rule to

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enable rewrite module from apache

Open terminal and execute following code

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now to avail use of rewrite module, follow the steps given below.

> 1. Open the default Apache configuration file in any editor by using following command.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

> 2. Inside that file, you will find the  block on line 1. Inside of that block, add the following block:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Again restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To know more about rewrite module [Click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

- **Note:** Make sure you have dedicated server to perform the above steps.